# testng.xml configurable file default location idenitification

Tags: testng

While executing code,in default, the testng-customsuite is generated in temp folder. how can i modify from temp folder to some other local driver. Also  can I use the same file for further modification like parallel , dataloader or i need to create the files externally. Please clarify

[TestNG] Running:
      C:\Users\GOWTHAM\AppData\Local\Temp\testng-eclipse--876953281\testng- customsuite.xml

Answer (score 0):

Create a `testng.xml` file in your project root folder and run your TestNG project by right clicking on it in Eclipse. So in this case your code will use this xml instead of generating one in runtime.